# No change over time. How to continue analysis?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, growth-model

I would like to conduct a growth curve analysis on longitudinal data. I have read that it is wise to begin with an unconditional means model first, and then move on to random intercepts, and random intercepts and slopes models. For a variable, the unconditional means (also called as one-way ANOVA with random effects) model seems to be the best. How should I continue? How to report or plot my findings if there is no change in time?

Thank you.